# ERROR while trying to connect to an oracle DB from R studio

Tags: r, oracle, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to an oracle database using R.
I did this code:

```
` library(ROracle)
 drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
 conn <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "DB_NAME") `
```

But I get this ERROR :
Erreur dans .oci.Connect(.oci.drv(), username = username, password = password,  :

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

But I'm sure that the username and password are correct.
Any help please?

Connecting to oracle DB from R with dbConnect.
But Getting an ERROR

Comment: Your username is wrong, or your password is wrong, or you aren't connecting to what you think you are. Just a guess but perhaps you're using the wrong service name, and connecting to a CDB instead of a PDB?

Comment: How can I check?